# On Windows 10, how can I know which app is consuming my memory?

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, docker, memory-leaks

I have 32G memory on my PC, which is extremely large.

I ran docker in windows.

I found my memory usage is extremly high (90%),

I closed all my programs.

and I found 59%+ memory usage, wait for a night, still not released.

[image]

How to know which app is consuming the "orange area" memory? which cost 12G space.

- green area memory means: reserved for hardware
- orange area memory means: modified/changed memory
- dark blue area means: used memory
- light blue area means: available

I cannot find any clue on task-manager, resource-manager, so what can I do?  do I need to buy a 128G memory PC for running docker (which only cost 6G ram at runtime )?

Comment: In Resource Monitor (Windows Admin Tools, Resource Monitor), make sure the Memory line is open so as to see all the processes. Let it run for 15 minutes and see if one or two processes sift to the top.

Comment: The problem is that modified memory does not include running processes.  Modified memory is the result of a process that required the memory and then never returned it to the OS.  You can likely avoid this situation by increasing your page file.  Honestly, the memory is likely being held by a suspended VM (Docker).

Comment: I can see VMware using less memory than it apparently started with in the "Working" column of Resource Monitor. This may not be the same as for Docker.  My comment may not be correct.

Comment: I should add that due to the fact the picture is not in English, means my analysis might be wrong.